# как вручную установить библиотеку phpoffice/phpword на PHP

Tags: php, phpword

Пробую с помощью composer сгенерировать библиотеку. Пробую писать по вот этому уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABUsfdD4HlQ

там указано, что можно подключать библиотки вручную... и у меня соответсвенно вопрос: Как это сделать?

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\phpWord();
print_r($phpWord);
$PhpWord -> setDefaultFontName('Temes New Roman');
$PhpWord -> setDefaultSize(14);

$properties = $PhpWord->getDocInfo();
$properties -> setCreator('My Name');
$properties -> setCompany('My factory');
$properties -> setTitle('My title');
$properties -> setDescription('My Description');
$properties -> setCategory('My Category');
$properties -> LastModified('MyName');
$properties -> setCreated('mktime(0,0,0,3,14,2014)');
$properties -> setModified(mktime(0,0,0,3,14,2014));
$properties -> setSubject('MySubject');
$properties -> setKeyWords('my, key, word');

$sectionStyle= array(
         'orientation' => 'landscape',
         'marginTop' =>PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pixelToTwip(150),
         'marginLeft' => 600,
         'marginRight' => 600,
         'ColsNuw' => 1,
         'pageNumbering Start' => 1,
         'borderBottomSize' =>100,
         'borderBottomColor'=> 'COCOCO'

);

$section = $PhpWord->AddSection($sectionStyle);
$Text="Здесь будет всё чики-пуки";
$section -> AddText(htmlSpecialChars($Text),
                                 array('Name=>', 'Arial', 'Size'=>36,
                                 'color'=>'0,75, 776', Bold=>true,
                                 'Italic'=>TRUE ),

                                 array('align' => 'right', 'SpaceBefore' =>5000

                                 ));
$ObjWriter=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IoFactory::createWriter($PhpWord, 'Word2007');




$ObjWriter->Save('doc.docx');
```

Comment: У вас проблема в чём? Подключить либу? Сгенерировать либу? Где либа? При чём здесь этот код? Что вы делали? Что получилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoloader.php для PHPExcel

```
<?php
PHPExcel_Autoloader::Register();
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
PHPExcel_Shared_String::buildCharacterSets();

class PHPExcel_Autoloader
{
    public static function Register() {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }
        //    Register ourselves with SPL
        return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
    }   //    function Register()

    public static function Load($pClassName){
        if ((class_exists($pClassName,FALSE)) || (strpos($pClassName, 'PHPExcel') !== 0)) {
            //    Either already loaded, or not a PHPExcel class request
            return FALSE;
        }

        $pClassFilePath = PHPEXCEL_ROOT .
                      str_replace('_',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$pClassName) .
                      '.php';

        if ((file_exists($pClassFilePath) === FALSE) || (is_readable($pClassFilePath) === FALSE)) {
            //    Can't load
            return FALSE;
        }

        require($pClassFilePath);
    }   //    function Load()

}
```

Autoloader.php для PHPWord

```
<?php
namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord;

class Autoloader
{
    const NAMESPACE_PREFIX = 'PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\';

    public static function register($throw = true, $prepend = false)
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'), $throw, $prepend);
    }

    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        $prefixLength = strlen(self::NAMESPACE_PREFIX);
        if (0 === strncmp(self::NAMESPACE_PREFIX, $class, $prefixLength)) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, substr($class, $prefixLength));
            $file = realpath(__DIR__ . (empty($file) ? '' : DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . $file . '.php');
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection Dynamic includes */
                require_once $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

убраны копирайты и большинство комментариев для краткости, все права принадлежат разработчикам PHPOffice.

Comment: Autoloader.php для PHPWord - ничё не работает!

Comment: @skinny ответ был дан больше года назад, как думаете, сколько обновлений прошла библиотека?