# При обращении к классу возникает ошибка php

Tags: php, phpword

Я только начинающий... сейчас работаю по вот этому уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABUsfdD4HlQ

Я уже долгое время мучаюсь с вот этой ошибкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
print_r($phpWord);
$PhpWord -> setDefaultFontName('Temes New Roman');
$PhpWord -> setDefaultSize(14);

$properties = $PhpWord->getDocInfo();
$properties -> setCreator('My Name');
$properties -> setCompany('My factory');
$properties -> setTitle('My title');
$properties -> setDescription('My Description');
$properties -> setCategory('My Category');
$properties -> LastModified('MyName');
$properties -> setCreated('mktime(0,0,0,3,14,2014)');
$properties -> setModified(mktime(0,0,0,3,14,2014));
$properties -> setSubject('MySubject');
$properties -> setKeyWords('my, key, word');

$sectionStyle= array(
         'orientation' => 'landscape',
         'marginTop' =>PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pixelToTwip(150),
         'marginLeft' => 600,
         'marginRight' => 600,
         'ColsNuw' => 1,
         'pageNumbering Start' => 1,
         'borderBottomSize' =>100,
         'borderBottomColor'=> 'COCOCO'

);

$section = $PhpWord->AddSection($sectionStyle);
$Text="Здесь будет всё чики-пуки";
$section -> AddText(htmlSpecialChars($Text),
                                   array('Name=>', 'Arial', 'Size'=>36,
                                   'color'=>'0,75, 776', Bold=>true,
                                   'Italic'=>TRUE ),

                                   array('align' => 'right', 'SpaceBefore' =>5000

                                   ));
$ObjWriter=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IoFactory::createWriter($PhpWord, 'Word2007');




$ObjWriter->Save('doc.docx');
```

может быть у меня проблема доступа из за расположения файлов...
 вот доступ к библиотеке E:\OSPanel\domains\diplom\vendor\phpoffice\phpword

Comment: Пространноство имён совпадает... паки совпадают

Comment: Autoload.php для PHPWord беру отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725496/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-phpoffice-phpword-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php/725574#725574

Comment: `Autoload.php для PHPWord беру отсюда ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725496/` - вот видимо в этом и есть косяк. Потому что если скачать phpword через composer то всё работает нормально..... как минимум я не вижу у тебя тут подключения этого автолоадера